# quarkus telemetry logging disable at runtime

Tags: java, logging, microservices, quarkus, open-telemetry

Is it possible to turn off open telemetry logging while opentelementry is enabled in Quarkus 2.x?

Looking for something similar to io.opentelemetry.level = OFF

Basically, i want to provide the ability to turn off telemetry logging for one of the services in the chain while continuing to propagate trace id/span ids. Any idea how to do this and how this can be configurable at runtime?

Thanks
SG

Comment: can you clarify, do you mean diagnostic logs from the OpenTelemetry SDK itself? or application logs being exported by OpenTelemetry?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to logs as a signal being exported by OpenTelemetry (like Traces and Metrics), you can set the following environment variable:

```
OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=none
```

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/sdk-configuration/general-sdk-configuration/#otel_logs_exporter

If you meant diagnostic logs from the OpenTelemetry SDK itself, you can use the following environment variable:

```
OTEL_JAVAAGENT_LOGGING=none
```

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/#javaagent-logging-output

You may need to use none with quotes: `"none"`.

Comment: Thanks . I am trying to follow the Quarkus link for enabling open telemetry. One of the properties i found useful to control how much gets traced is quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.sampler=ratio and quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.sampler.ratio=0. This works fine when i specify in the application.properties but not from application.yaml: . Tried using the below with no luck. quarkus:
  opentelemetry:
    tracer:
      sampler:
        ~: ratio
        ratio: 1 - Using this ~ sign based on the link: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml#configuration-key-conflicts

Comment: Is your question about logs or traces sampling? If it is about sampling, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus does not yet support OpenTelemetry logging. The support is planned.
No need for any config to disable it.